# php 7.2 create_function deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, elfinder

hello I get this error in php7.2, anyone can help me to fix it

```
$_getcmd = create_function('$cmd', 'list($ret) = explode(\'.\', $cmd);return trim($ret);');
```

Comment: What is your question? The function was deprecated as of php 7.2 per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php and will be removed at some point in a future version of php.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's depricated in php 7.2

You can make use of anynoumous function

```
$_getcmd = function($cmd) {
    list($ret) = explode('.', $cmd);

    return trim($ret);
};
```